# Hierarchical / Multi-index operations in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a multi-index dataframe like the following:

```
                     A         B         C
X      Y                              
bar   one    -0.007381 -0.365315 -0.024817
      two    -1.219794  0.370955 -0.795125
baz   one     0.145578  1.428502 -0.408384
      two    -0.249321 -0.292967 -1.849202
      three  -0.249321 -0.292967 -1.849202
      four    0.21     -0.967123  1.202234
foo   one    -1.046479 -1.250595  0.781722
      two     1.314373  0.333150  0.133331
qux   one     0.716789  0.616471 -0.298493
      two     0.385795 -0.915417 -1.367644
```

I would like to get the **maximum value** of `A` for each value of the first level (`X`), and collect the **second level index** when  this happens.

How can I do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [87]: df.loc[df['A'].groupby(level='X').idxmax(), 'A']
Out[87]: 
X    Y   
bar  one    -0.007381
baz  four    0.210000
foo  two     1.314373
qux  one     0.716789
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

---

To find the median *values*, you could use

```
df['A'].groupby(level='X').median()
```

but it is less clear which row should be associated with the median, since if there is an even number of rows in a group, the *average* of the middle rows is used to compute the median.
The median is thus not associated with one row, but rather two.

If you make an arbitrary decision, such as wanting the `n//2`th row (rather than the `(n-1)//2`th row), then you could use

```
grouped =  df['A'].groupby(level='X', sort=True)
df.loc[grouped.apply(lambda grp: grp.index[grp.count()//2]), 'A']
```

to find both the median value and an "associated" row.

For example,

```
In [93]: df.loc[grouped.apply(lambda grp: grp.index[grp.count()//2]), 'A']
Out[93]: 
X    Y    
bar  two     -1.219794
baz  three   -0.249321
foo  two      1.314373
qux  two      0.385795
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks. Building on this and trying to make this solution as general as possible. How would I find something more generic, such as the `median` (and its index) as opposed to the maximum value?

Comment: The median is more tricky. I've taken a shot at it above. In general, I think you would need to find a formula for *the index* of the row you are looking for, and then use `df.loc` to pick off that row.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `groupby` object:

```
groups = df['A'].groupby(level='X')
groups.min()
```